# stub an instance variable using mocha

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, stub, testunit

Let's say I have a method that references an instance variable directly:

```
class MyClass
  def method1
    puts @instance_var
  end
end
```

How can I stub out the value of `@instance_var` using `mocha` in a `Test::Unit` test?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not considered a best practice to access an object's instance variables directly from a unit test, if you have a good reason for doing this, you can use [`instance_variable_set`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set):

```
my_instance = MyClass.new
my_instance.instance_variable_set(:@instance_var, 'My updated value')
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't. That's one of the many reasons why you should never access ivars directly.

Comment: Care to elaborate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981614/is-it-bad-form-to-use-instance-vars-directly-in-ruby

Comment: OO is about message sending. Accessing an ivar is not a message send, therefore it is not OO. Ruby is an object-oriented language, so it makes sense to strive for an object-oriented design, ergo not accessing ivars. Or, to go by a different definition of OO: what distinguishes OOP from ADT-oriented programming is Representation Independence and specifically the ability to support Multiple Representations. Accessing ivars breaks both Representation Independence and Multiple Representations. In addition to that, it also breaks inheritance since you cannot override ivars, only methods.

Comment: I think you're talking about original OOP. Modern definition of OOP has gone away from that. Not sure what you mean by not being able to override ivars. Ruby is a dynamically typed language, can't a child object put whatever into the ivar? I have a specific case here. I don't intend the outside world to access that particular ivar.